# What would cause Flask-WTForms to return None for every field?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, python-3.7, quart

I have several forms which all work as expected when I run the app locally.

But when I attempt to use any form on the same app proxied via nginx every form returns `None` for each field.

If I print the `form.data` it returns:

```
{'display_name': None, 'password': None, 'csrf_token': None}
```

The browser shows the form data/post request data as:

```
csrf_token: <an actual and matching csrf token>
display_name: jack
password: <the_actual_password>
remember_me: on
submit: Login
```

The relevant part of the nginx config:

```
upstream quart_app {
    server 10.217.0.130:8651;
}

server {
    server_name          quart_app.url; # This is a proper url normally
    listen               443 ssl http2;
    listen               [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/quart_app/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/quart_app/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    add_header           "Strict-Transport-Security" "max-age=15768000";

    access_log           logs/quart_app.access.log main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass             https://quart_app;
        proxy_set_header       Host $host;
        proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header       'Upgrade' $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header       'Connection' 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header       'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        proxy_set_header       'Accept-Encoding' 'br';
        proxy_set_header       'Service-Worker-Allowed' '/';
        proxy_set_header       'Pragma' 'public';
        proxy_set_header       'Cache-Control' 'public';
        proxy_set_header       'Vary' 'Accept-Encoding';

    }

}
```

I know this has nothing to do with my Quart code itself as it is the same code (git cloned) that works fine when using the development server locally.

What could possibly be causing this to happen.

Comment: You may want to share the nginx configuration as well

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, done